# Conflicting page numbering using \input{}

Tags: page-numbering

Basically, i divided my document into several sections, each is in .tex file and combined them in a "main.tex" document with `\input{}` as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
% --------------- 
\input{title}
\newpage
\tableofcontents

\input{intro}
\input{another}


% ----------------
\end{document}
```

intro.tex

```
\begin{titlepage}
\section{Introduction}
  blah blah blah
\subsection{Bla Bla bla}
    more text goes here
\subsubsection{Examples}
   additional text
\end{titlepage}
```

another.tex

```
\begin{titlepage}
\section{Introduction}
  blah blah blah
\end{titlepage}
```

[image: The page of contents]
It can be seen that page numbering is not coherent. why is this happening ?

I'm sorry if this is a duplicate but i've searched everywhere for a solution and couldn't find any.

Comment: your question asks about `\include` but your example uses `\input` these are very different commands, which did you intend to ask about?

Comment: please provide the three small files `title.tex` , `intro.tex` and `another.tex` that are needed to produce the output shown. It is impossible to debug code you can not see,

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks, i have provided extra details

Comment: What's the purpose of `titlepage` in the `\input` files?

Comment: `titlepage` is resetting the page number each time. this is unrelated to `\input` you would see the same if you had that all in one file

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks mate, problem solved. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is unrelated to `\input`. the pagenumbering is being reset to 1 by the `titlepage` environment, you should simply delete that for your normal sections, also both your sections have the same title, "Introduction"  which is rather confusing.