# page numbering broken with input

Tags: page-numbering

I tried to number page. However, it doesn't work the way I want. I would like the numbering to change after the table of contents. After that, I would like arabic numbers and romanian numbers before that. I get the arabic number but both my copyright page and my table of contents are numbered i.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa, sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\title{title}
\author{Me}
\date{}
\usepackage{fullpage}

\edef\restoreparindent{\parindent=\the\parindent\relax}
\usepackage{parskip}
\restoreparindent

\makeindex


\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{Roman}

\input{titlepage}


\chapterfont{\centering}

\pagebreak
\input{Copyright}

\input{Abstract}



\tableofcontents{}


\chapter{Introduction}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\pagebreak


\section{section_name}

\section{section_name}

\section{section_name}



\chapter{Théorie}



\listoffigures



\end{document}
```

Here is my Abstract :

```
\begin{abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
\ipsum
\vfill
\end{abstract}
```

Here is my title page :

```
\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}
        \vspace*{1cm}
        
        {\tiny \hrule height 0.001pt}
        \vspace{5pt}
        \setlength{\baselineskip}{1.2\baselineskip} \textsf{{\LARGE title}} \par
        \vspace{13pt}
        {\tiny \hrule height 0.01pt}
        
        
        \textbf{Me}
        
        \vfill
        
        \vspace{0.8cm}
        
        \large
        
    \end{center}
\end{titlepage}
```

Here is my copyright page :

```
\vspace*{\fill}
\begingroup\centering
\copyright \: Me\\
\vspace{15pt}

\endgroup
\vspace*{\fill}

\pagebreak
```

What is wrong ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would have used `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` as they are more traditional. Where exactly is the introduction suppose to be? If with Arabic, I'd have the change be before chapter, not after

Comment: I use a document so it's not possible. I will change that to get introduction numbered with arabic number. Anyway, I will add more elements before the table of contents so I would like to fix the numbering.

Comment: Please explain, this comment does not make much sense

Comment: I need the page numbering to be fixed without numbering manually every page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/462988/conflicting-page-numbering-using-input) worked. The titlepage environment resets the numbering. You can write:

```
\pagenumbering{roman}
\input{titlepage}
\setcounter{page}{2}
```